# Want to apply some code to second scene on same storyboard (Xcode, Swift 2)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Extreme noob here just getting into Swift and iOS development.

I have already created the basic design for my app in storyboard and inserted some basic code.

Right now I want to do the following but am pretty stuck.

- Record the time between an event happening on screen and touch input from the user.
  So basically, the even happens on screens and sets off a timer, the timer stops when the user touches the screen and records the value.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to get interval between two events.

```
let start = NSDate()
// do stuff...
let timeInterval = start.timeIntervalSinceNow()
```

When event started,(Use first line to record event begin time) you will obviously know. And the user when touches screen few delegate methods will be fired(Use second line here to know time interval). Below is the code for that.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

view.userInteractionEnabled = true

self.view.addSubview(view)


 func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     print("Hello World")
  }
```

Comment: Updated to swift. Thanks ;-)